# How to set a uitableviewcell unclickable on the iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Hi I'm trying to have my uitableviewcell rendered inactive so that a user can't click but merely say the data in the cell.  I attempt to do so with:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
if (indexPath.row < factsCount) {
static NSString *FactsCellIdentifier = @"FactsCell";
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:FactsCellIdentifier];
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

However the cell can still be clicked and highlighted.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To stop just some cells being selected use:

```
cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

As well as preventing selection, this also stops tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: being called for the cells that have it set.

(but note that it will disable any interactive content within the cells - eg. buttons - for that case, set selectionStyle to UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone and ignore the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: call for that cell)

Comment: I've noticed that in some cases, one must explicitly set the color of the text to black (or any color) to prevent it from turning gray, which cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO; seems to automatically do. Just something to be aware of.

Comment: FYI if you have buttons in your cell, they will also be disabled.  In that case you want Ole's answer

Comment: @Jameo very true - I've updated my answer to mention that, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Set the cell's `selectionStyle` to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`.

Comment: the cell is still clickable after I implement this. i have updated my question with the code.

Comment: Technically, the cell is still clickable but the user does not see the selection. Of course, you must also ensure that your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` implementation does nothing for this particular cell.

Comment: If you have a button inside the cell, this is the solution that works

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

or

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

Answer (score 4):

To disable cell selection you can implement `-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method in table view delegate and return nil if you don't want cell with given NSIndexPath to be selected.
As already pointed in other answers to disable cell highlighting you should set its selectionStyle property to UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone.
Also make sure that you set properties correctly when reusing tableviewcells